# Replacing environment variables in bashrc

Tags: bash

I can retrieve a list of environment variables from a remote system, which prints out the environment variable like this:

```
some command | awk -F ": " '/SOME_VAR/ {print "export "$1"="$2}'
```

will give

```
export SOME_VAR_ABC=999
export SOME_VAR_XYZ=123
export SOME_VAR_TUV=654
etc
```

Is there a way I can then loop through and write these directly to my bashrc, but overwrite the variable if it already exists?

Comment: Just append the lines to the end of your file. There's virtually no reason to go to the trouble of automatically overwriting the previous assignments.

Comment: if I run this script every week, then my bashrc could end up with lots of duplicates..

Comment: Why are you updating this weekly? Perhaps a better idea would be to source a second file whose contents are replaced weekly, rather than appending.

Comment: That is, just add `. remote_vars` to your `.bash_profile` (recommended for environment variables over `.bashrc`), and run `some command | awk ... > remote_vars` weekly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe a cleaner way to avoid duplicates of the variables you retrieve from the remote machine (which makes me think their value may change over time) is to write them down to a separate file apart from your `.bashrc` and then load that file into your `.bashrc` file.

For example, let's call it `~/.custom_variables`. To get the variables retrieved from the remote machine into this file, you can run the following command:

```
some command | awk -F ": " '/SOME_VAR/ {print "export "$1"="$2}' > ~/.custom_variables
```

And then you would only have to add this to your `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -f ~/.custom_variables ]; then
  source ~/.custom_variables
fi
```

This way every time you run that command the file `~/.custom_variables` will be overwritten, and thus you would not have to worry about duplicate entries.